# Where does Signal store private messages, and how can I restore from a backup?

Tags: signal-messenger

I was previously using Ubuntu. Now I've moved to Debian. Where did `signal-desktop` for Linux store private messages?

I checked for a `~/.signal` and the like, the app was installed to `/opt`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently it stores the user data in

```
/home/$USER/.config/Signal
```

If you migrate that directory `signal-desktop` will seamlessly start as before.

Comment: And `/home/$USER/snap/signal-desktop/current/.config/Signal/` with snap on Ubuntu 20.10. The storage does not appear to be encrypted BTW: https://www.reddit.com/r/privacy/comments/fwux29/signal_desktop_stores_the_encryption_key_in_a/

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed using `flatpak` on Linux then the location is `$HOME/.var/app/org.signal.Signal/config`. I managed to restore signal messages from Windows10/11 to PopOS by copying to

```
$HOME/.var/app/org.signal.Signal/config/Signal/
```

The screenshot shows the files I copied.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: This answer may have been downvoted due to a potential inaccuracy. The location mentioned is only applicable when using a Flatpak. However, instead of a downvote, a simple correction may have sufficed.